# Google Sheets - Conditional formatting rules

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I have a situation with this text:

"What do you want?
Foil.
What covarage do you want?
Fullbody."

More specifically, in the text above I want that the row to be automatic in a certain color if the text ends with:
"What covarage do you want?
Fullbody. "

I tried to add this condition, but without success:

*The text ends with:

"What covarage do you want?

Fullbody. "*

It didn't work, because the word `Fullbody` is on another line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Share a sample workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1, "What covarage do you want\?\nFullbody$")
```

[image]

`?` is escaped with `\?`
new line is `\n`
`$` means "ends with"

Comment: Tried with your code, but I recieve an error: Invalid formula.

Comment: @Paul try: `=REGEXMATCH(A1; "What covarage do you want\?\nFullbody$")`

Comment: Hello, I observed that the function works only when I write something on the "B" column. Do you have any idea why is this happening?